# What steps should we follow while changing the datatype of a primary key in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, primary-key, alter

I have a table similar to this.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL,
    customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY_KEY (customer_id)
);
```

with some values in the table.

I want to change the data type of the primary key `customer_id` to `NUMBER(10, 0)`. So what steps do we follow before executing the `ALTER` command? (This column is not being referenced as a foreign key in any table)

Specifically,

We have an index on the primary column by default in oracle SQL. So should we drop the primary key constraint and then execute the `ALTER` command?
And any other considerations we need to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For case like yours, you don't have to do anything - just *do it*:

```
SQL> create table customers (
  2  customer_id number(7, 0),
  3  customer_name varchar2(50),
  4  constraint customer_pk primary key (customer_id));

Table created.

SQL> insert into customers
  2  select 1234566, 'Little' from dual union all
  3  select 98876  , 'Foot'   from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> alter table customers modify customer_id number(8, 0);

Table altered.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'CUSTOMERS';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
CUSTOMER_PK

SQL>
```

But, if you had to make the column *smaller* or modify its datatype - that's another story. Lucky you, not yours.